# how send function address from class1 to class2

Tags: c++11, static, arm, keil

c++11 / arm compiler v6.9 / keil5

i have 2 class ( class1, class2 ) - i whant send a function address from class1 to class 2, but i cant - i must define my function static - but i don't want do this

```
// ---------------------------- CLASS1.CPP ----------------------------
void CLASS1::ControlTransfer(uint8_t Physical_EPn, uint8_t bEPStatus) {
 // ...
}

void CLASS1::init() {
    class2.intHandler(2, ControlTransfer); // error: reference to non-static member function must be called
}

// ---------------------------- CLASS2.H ----------------------------
typedef void (TFnEPIntHandler)  (uint8_t Physical_EPn, uint8_t bEPStatus);

// ---------------------------- CLASS2.CPP ----------------------------
TFnEPIntHandler *_apfnEPIntHandlers[16];

void CLASS2::intHandler( uint8_t num, TFnEPIntHandler *pfnHandler ) {
    _apfnEPIntHandlers[ num ] = pfnHandler;
}

// _apfnEPIntHandlers used in my interrupt function
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-static member function like `CLASS1::ControlTransfer` can't be called without knowing what `CLASS1` object to call it on.  And a raw pointer to function like your `TFnEPIntHandler` just doesn't contain enough information to specify that object.

If you can, consider changing the raw function pointers to the more flexible `std::function` type:

```
// In a header file:
#include <functional>
using TFnEPIntHandler = std::function<void(uint8_t, uint8_t)>;

// TFnEPIntHandler should now be used directly, not as a pointer.
// (Note a std::function can "act like" a null pointer.)
TFnEPIntHandler _apfnEPIntHandlers[16];
void CLASS2::intHandler( uint8_t num, TFnEPIntHandler pfnHandler ) {
    _apfnEPIntHandlers[ num ] = std::move(pfnHandler);
}

// Replace CLASS1::init():
void CLASS1::init() {
    // Use a lambda which captures the "this" pointer and can be
    // converted to the std::function type.  The function must not
    // be used after this CLASS1 object is destroyed!
    class2.intHandler(2, [this](uint8_t Physical_EPn, uint8_t bEPStatus)
        { ControlTransfer(Physical_EPn, bEPStatus); });
}
```

If `std::function` is not an option because you need to interface with C code, you could add an extra `void*` parameter to the function type, and use wrapper functions which cast that pointer to the class type to call the real non-static member function.  For example:

```
class CLASS1 {
// ...
private:
    static void ControlTransferCB(uint8_t Physical_EPn,
                                  uint8_t bEPStatus,
                                  void* extra)
    {
        static_cast<CLASS1*>(extra)->ControlTransfer(Physical_EPn, bEPStatus);
    }
// ...
};
```

The extra `void*` argument could be provided to `CLASS2::intHandler` (which implies there should be an array of structs of function pointers and extra `void*` data), or to other logic that actually invokes the functions, whichever is more appropriate.